# Line rate and frame rate

Tags: resolution

I don't know how to determine line rate and frame rate of the following system:

```
Height of monitor:            40cm
Screen Aspect Ratio:          16:9
Pixel Aspect Ratio:           4:3
Progressive scan
Viewing distance from screen: 0.6m
Active line period:           15μs 
Horizontal Blanking:          5μs 
Vertical blanking lines:      20
```

Comment: This isn't enough information above to determine the frame rate.  Something like a number of lines or a number of pixels or a pixel clock is required.

Comment: That's all information given in this problem. What if I set a number of pixels or a number of lines? What about the line rate?